# nav bar after scroll stretch too much

Tags: html, css

I have nav bar and I'm using js to make my nav bar position fixed. After scrolling down because i adding width 100% my nav bar stretch more then it should and it goes over my layout

my script

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
 if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
  $('nav').addClass('sticky');
 } else {
  $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
 }
})
```

Css

```
.sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

link to website so you can see what is happening is [click here](https://www.mzacharias.co.uk/project/index.php)

Comment: can you clarify the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I recomend you to use the position stick property

For example: `nav { position: sticky; top: 0px; }`. You should use it inside a container with height defined.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning

Answer (score 1):

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

could be your problem here.
**Change 100% to the actual width you want**, because your object is leaving the header object with a static positioning and as so the width isn't regulated any more. **This fix is quick but also dirty.** Consider changes in your layout have to be applied to all divs with static width, as well as responsive features are harder to implement. Option B would be a much better solution here.

Another solution is to insert a  between the page div and your objects and set the fixed width there.  Sub-divs allow for aligning objects.  Inside objects at 100% width will line up to the next div up in the document tree.

Answer (score 1):

```
.sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
```

}

Here you just can give the width value in pixels, what you want. Or if you wanna use it with relative values, you can make a container for it, because it will count the position from the parent element, give a fix width value to the container, and add your element to it.